# What other definitions for a planet were proposed?

Tags: history, pluto, definition

[This article from the IAU](https://www.iau.org/public/themes/pluto/) states

> The first draft proposal for the definition of a planet was debated vigorously by astronomers at the 2006 IAU General Assembly in Prague and a new version slowly took shape. This new version was more acceptable to the majority

What were the other proposals for the definition of a planet? What was changed between the first draft and the final version that was voted on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IAU website has this [draft definition of "planet" and "plutons"](https://www.iau.org/news/pressreleases/detail/iau0601/) page, published on 16 August 2006 in Prague. It says (emphasis mine):

> The world's astronomers, under the auspices of the International
> Astronomical Union (IAU), have concluded two years of work defining
> the difference between "planets" and the smaller "solar system bodies"
> such as comets and asteroids. If the definition is approved by the
> astronomers gathered 14-25 August 2006 at the IAU General Assembly in
> Prague, our Solar System will include 12 planets, with more to come:
> eight classical planets that dominate the system, three planets in a
> new and growing category of "plutons" - Pluto-like objects - and
> Ceres. *Pluto remains a planet and is the prototype for the new
> category of "plutons."*

The proposed 12 planets Solar System looked like this (credit: The International Astronomical Union/Martin Kornmesser):

[image]

The [final press release](https://www.iau.org/news/pressreleases/detail/iau0603/), published on 24 August 2006, says:

> The IAU members gathered at the 2006 General Assembly agreed that a
> "planet" is defined as a celestial body that (a) is in orbit around
> the Sun, (b) has sufficient mass for its self-gravity to overcome
> rigid body forces so that it assumes a hydrostatic equilibrium (nearly
> round) shape, and (c) has cleared the neighbourhood around its orbit.
>
> This means that the Solar System consists of eight "planets" Mercury,
> Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune. A new
> distinct class of objects called "dwarf planets" was also decided. It
> was agreed that "planets" and "dwarf planets" are two distinct classes
> of objects. The first members of the "dwarf planet" category are
> Ceres, Pluto and 2003 UB313 (temporary name).

Which looked like this (credit: The International Astronomical Union/Martin Kornmesser):

[image]

So in 8 days, the IAU switched from a 12 planets system, with a planet subcategory called "plutons", to a 8 planets system, with an dwarf planet category distinct from the planet category. How did that happen? It's probably something only a General Assembly attendant who witnessed the discussion would know. It must have been quite a debate!